# When (at which moment) is __destruct called?

Tags: php, garbage-collection, reference-counting

Is there some assurance when __destruct is called, when considering simple objects without reference cycles? I know from java, that it is not defined when and if the function finalize is called, it depends on the garbage collector.

For example if you have a function like:

```
1   function test(){
2       $x = new SomeObject();
3       $y = new SomeObject();
4       $x = null;
5   }
```

Where `SomeObject` has no reference cycles.

Can you assume `$x->__destruct` is called at line 4 and `$y->__destruct` is called at line 5?

Testing the following script seems to indicate that this is true:
https://gist.github.com/KAYLukas/0b1d65e57b52862f8da5

Furthermore, `SplFileObject` seems to work on this predicate: it is impossible to close the file, instead you just need to set the variable to null. If this would not call `__destruct` directly it would be impossible to open the file reliable after it has been opened with `SplFileObject`.

I have found that there is an assurance that the `__destruct` will be called eventually, just not when.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can assume that.

`__destruct` is always called at the moment where the last reference to the object disappears: when you can't access that object anymore in any way from the outside.

If there exist circular references, you need to wait until it circular garbage collector comes in, where it isn't defined at what point that happens.

If you have stored the object somewhere else too, you need to first remove it from there before the destructor is called.

For further information: Internal objects don't always destruct their resources upon `__destruct` (as the user might call it directly), but only when the object really is destroyed. (technical measure to prevent segfaults)

Also during shutdown, first variables and arrays are removed in the **reverse** order they were defined and where the last reference to an object disappears the object is destroyed. Then circular garbage collector comes in and removes the other objects and calls `__destruct` there.

The only thing which is undefined here, is the order in which the **circular** garbage collector removes objects and calls their `__destruct` function.

Comment: 'when you can't access that object anymore in any way from the outside.' Is not completely true, consider the object: https://gist.github.com/KAYLukas/5d91aa17c6173f426a7d . The destructor will only be called when the gc (circular reference collector) has been run.

Anyway, (samitha commented the documentation) the documentation says: 'The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.' So if you update your answer I will accept it.

Comment: @user23127 actually most of that is already implicitly stated in my answer. But I have updated it with information. Also during shutdown it's not _in any order_, but in a known order, but just not documented.

Comment: @user23127 little mistake, variables are actually destroyed in __reverse order__ http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_execute_API.c#247 corrected that.

Comment: for my purpose I'm not considering how it is done now - that is easily found out by testing - , but if it is documented, and as such won't change in subsequent updates.

Comment: @user23127 actually, most things here aren't documented and are effectively subject to change. But as far as I can tell now, (being contributor to php-src) there are no plans to change that actually. So you should be safe for at least the next two versions I think.